# I want to construct a local Git repository. I am using the config file. I got an error

Tags: git, macos

My config file is

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = /Users/voloda2/safe/tut:tut.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I got an error: git push
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /Users/voloda2/safe/tut: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

### fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

[image]

Comment: What command did you use ? I think the issue is coming from here because git is trying to connect to a local file useing `ssh` as though it was a hostname (and that obsviously cannot work).

Comment: +1 try to change /Users/voloda2/safe/tut:tut.git to /Users/voloda2/safe/tut.git

Comment: fatal: '/Users/voloda2/safe/tut.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the section on URLs in the [git clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a) documentation, you'll see that it says that:

```
[user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git
```

... is equivalent to:

```
ssh://[user@]host.xz/~/path/to/repo.git
```

Since the `[user@]` indicates that `user@` is optional, it's trying to interpret `/Users/voloda2/safe/tut:tut.git` as an `scp`-style specification for a repository over SSH.  (The host is assumed to be called `/Users/voloda2/safe/tut`, with the path `~/tut.git`)

It looks as if the repository should just be `/Users/voloda2/safe/tut/`, however, so try changing the URL to either of:

```
/Users/voloda2/safe/tut/
file:///Users/voloda2/safe/tut/
```

You can do that with:

```
git config remote.origin.url /Users/voloda2/safe/tut/
```

Comment: fatal: '/Users/voloda2/safe/tut:tut.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: @Voloda2: there's still a colon in the URL in that error - did you change it with the `git config` command as I suggested?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you're don't need to use some remote repo if you're don't want to share your files with co-workers.

Usual local workflow is:

`git init` in root of your project folder

`git add .` add all your files

```
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

make some change

`git add ChangedFile.c` or `git add .`

```
git commit -m "commit changes"
```

that's all. your changes are saved in local repository

PS There is a steps with local remote test.

```
mkdir /tmp/test.git
cd /tmp/test.git
git init --bare /tmp/test.git
git push /tmp/test.git +master
```

after that you can add /tmp/test.git as remote repository

```
git remote add origin /tmp/test.git
```

Comment: i want to use git push in educational aims.